# Rescuable after_commit callbacks (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a model with several `after_commit` callbacks. In case any of the callbacks raises an exception, all others will be skipped.

I want to ensure that all callbacks are ran (even if one fails), without explicitly wrapping each of them with `begin` & `rescue`.

Is there a way to so? I've looked into [rescuable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L568-L571) option of `CallbackChain` but it doesn't seem to be stuiable for this case

```rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :a, :b

    def a() puts 'in a' end
    def b() puts 'in b'; fail 'Bad callback' end
end
```

In this case, callback `a` will not run:

```
>> Order.create!
in b
[ERROR] Bad callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions in after_commit callbacks are ignored so that they do not interfere with other callbacks.

In your case 'in a' is not printing because your "a" function is not printing the string, it is simply returning the string. You forgot to use `puts`.
`def a() 'in a' end` should be `def a() puts 'in a' end`

As per the docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_validations_callbacks.html):

> The after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are guaranteed to be called for all models created, updated, or destroyed within a transaction block. If any exceptions are raised within one of these callbacks, they will be ignored so that they don’t interfere with the other callbacks.

Comment: No, `a` is not called, because `b`'s exception is not rescued, and according to the docs: "if your callback code could raise an exception, you’ll need to rescue it and handle it appropriately within the callback."